# How to populate an image as a link which are both stored in an array as JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Please click on my JSFiddle link to see the code in action for what I am trying do. As you will notice, I have the tile, image, and link stored as JSON objects, but when you run my code, it does not display my title and image as a link as specified in my HTML file, along with the specified in attributes. I've been working on this for a while now, and I can't figure it out, when it seems like something that should be rather obvious. Does anyone have any ideas, suggestions, or a solution for me? I tried setting the output in JavaScript to be "" but that did not work.

HTML:

```
<a id="food" class="thumbnail" target="_blank">
<img width="200" class="img-shadow">
<hr>
<h3></h3>
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var data={"food":[
{
    "title":"Pumpkin Spice Bread Recipe",
    "image":"img/bread.jpg",
    "link":"http://willowbirdbaking.com/2011/09/18/pumpkin-spice-pull-apart-
bread-with-butter-rum-glaze/"
    }
]}

var output="<ul>";
// Create a variable to temporarily store the data 
for (var i in data.food) {
    output+="<li>" + data.food[i].title + data.food[i].image +      data.food[i].link + "</li>";
}
output+="</ul>";
// Once we go through all of the elements in the array, 
// we use the output variable to populate the placeholder div.
document.getElementById("food").innerHTML=output;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XcpGN/6021/)

Thanks in advance, much appreciated for any bit of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `<img />` tag to output image. Your mistake is you just outputted image link.

Use image link tag: `var bob = "some text <img src='"+data.food[i].image+"' />";`

Try this:

```
var data={"food":[
{
    "title":"Pumpkin Spice Bread Recipe",
    "image":"img/bread.jpg",
    "link":"http://willowbirdbaking.com/2011/09/18/pumpkin-spice-pull-apart-
bread-with-butter-rum-glaze/"
    }
]}

var output="<ul>";
// Create a variable to temporarily store the data 
for (var i in data.food) {
    output+="<li>" + data.food[i].title + "<img src='"+data.food[i].image+"' /> " + data.food[i].link + "</li>";
}
output+="</ul>";
// Once we go through all of the elements in the array, 
// we use the output variable to populate the placeholder div.
document.getElementById("food").innerHTML=output;
```

If you want your image be the link you have to put your image into `<a></a>` tag like this:

```
for (var i in data.food) {
    output+="<li><a title='" + data.food[i].title + "' href='"+data.food[i].link+"'><img title='" + data.food[i].title + "' src='"+data.food[i].image+"' /></li>";
}
```

So final code:

```
var data={"food":[
{
    "title":"Pumpkin Spice Bread Recipe",
    "image":"img/bread.jpg",
    "link":"http://willowbirdbaking.com/2011/09/18/pumpkin-spice-pull-apart-
bread-with-butter-rum-glaze/"
    }
]}

var output="<ul>";
// Create a variable to temporarily store the data 
for (var i in data.food) {
    output+="<li><a title='" + data.food[i].title + "' href='"+data.food[i].link+"'>" + data.food[i].title + "<img title='" + data.food[i].title + "' src='"+data.food[i].image+"' /></li>";
}
output+="</ul>";
// Once we go through all of the elements in the array, 
// we use the output variable to populate the placeholder div.
document.getElementById("food").innerHTML=output;
```

And [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XcpGN/6026/).

Comment: thank you, very helpful. That is perfect except I was just wondering why the title is not being displayed in addition to the image?

Comment: I don't understand you a bit. Title now shown when you hover the image? I don't have this. All is working perfectly — [click me](http://i.gyazo.com/803461c53dc358e3c4ece4723e2b1e8b.png)

Comment: Sorry I did not explain well enough... I want the title to be displayed below the image, without needing to hover over it, just how I have it set up in the HTML. If I could have everything looking exactly how I have it specified in the HTML, I would have exactly what I want... Does that make more sense?

Comment: I updated my answer. I want to tell you a secret that sometimes you can change the code a bit and it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much, and thanks for the secret I will try to remember that haha

Answer (score 1):

It is inside the `<a>` tag. You just need a href attribute on it for it to look like a real link.